# Representing elements of $H_2$ of a group using the bar (or standard) chain complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a discrete group, and let $a_1,b_1,\ldots,a_g,b_g \in G$ be elements such that
$$[a_1,b_1] \cdots [a_g,b_g] = 1$$
in $G$.  These correspond to a map of a genus-$g$ surface group $\pi_1(\Sigma_g)$ to $G$.  This takes the fundamental class of $H_2(\pi_1(\Sigma_g)) = H_2(\Sigma_g) = \mathbb{Z}$ to some element $\lambda \in H_2(G)$.

We can compute $H_2(G)$ using the bar complex (also sometimes called the standard complex)
$$\cdots \rightarrow C_2(G) \rightarrow C_1(G) \rightarrow C_0(G) \rightarrow 0.$$
Here $C_n$ is the abelian group with basis the formal symbols $[x_1|\cdots|x_n]$ with each $x_i \in G$, and the boundary map is
$$d[x_1|x_2|\cdots|x_n] = [x_2|\cdots|x_n] - [x_1 x_2|x_3|\cdots|x_n] + \cdots + (-1)^{n-1} [x_1|\cdots|x_{n-1} x_n] + (-1)^n [x_1|\cdots|x_{n-1}].$$
**Question**: How can I represent $\lambda$ as a cycle in $C_2(G)$?

I only know how to do this if $g=1$.  In that case, $a_1$ and $b_1$ commute, and we can take the cycle $[a_1|b_1]-[b_1|a_1]$.  Note that the boundary of this is
$$([b_1] - [a_1 b_1] + [a_1])-([a_1]-[b_1 a_1]+[b_1]) = [a_1 b_1] - [b_1 a_1] = 0.$$
But I do not know how to handle higher $g$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/376972/81055 Here's a formula (which probably means that question can be treated as "already asked and answered")

Comment: A formula can be found in Exercise 4c of Chapter II.5 of Brown's book on group cohomology.